# curl put file from server to bullhorn using php

Tags: php, curl, put

I am trying to use curl and php to send a file from my liquid web server to the bullhorn vms system. I have tried multiple ways to get this to work but the current code i am using is:

```
    $url_path_str = 'https://rest91.bullhornstaffing.com/rest-services/(corp token)/file/Candidate/'.$entityid.'/raw?filetype=SAMPLE&externalID=portfolio?BhRestToken='.$bhresttoken;
    $file_path_str = '/home/path/'.$row["first_name"].$row["last_name"].'.pdf';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ''.$url_path_str.'');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);

    $fh_res = fopen($file_path_str, 'r');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh_res);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($file_path_str));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $curl_response_res = curl_exec ($ch);
    echo $url_path_str;
    echo $curl_response_res;
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fh_res);
```

The `$entityid`, `$bhresttoken`, `$row["first_name"]`, and `$row["last_name"]` are variables I have created and using echo shows that they are working. Two errors show up separately when I try to execute this code.

The first error is

> "{"errorMessage":"Missing 'BhRestToken' in request header or parameter.","errorMessageKey":"errors.authentication.missingRestToken","errorCode":412}"

which is weird because the bhresttoken allegedly isn't required but also it is definitely showing correctly at the end of the "url_path_str", so is it in the wrong spot?

The other issue that I get is

> "An error occurred while processing your request. Reference #179.24343217.1582146766.1f0b67".

From what I've been told the reference number is a generic issue so I'm guessing that my code is flawed somewhere however I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Any advice or input would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Should it be an & in `portfolio?BhRestToken`?

Comment: Besides the potential typo which @NigelRen mentioned. Can you log `$url_path_str` this variable and check this URL by hand if everything looks like expected?

Comment: When I switch the ? to a & I get "{"errorMessage":"Bad 'BhRestToken' or timed-out.","errorMessageKey":"errors.authentication.invalidRestToken","errorCode":401}" but everytime I execute the code it generates a new token so how is it possible the new code is bad or timed-out? Also when I echo out the url and check it by hand I get the same error message.

Comment: @ProfessionallyInept does the token contain any special characters which might need to be url encoded?

Comment: @Christoph Kluge The token contains only numbers, letters, and dashes.